# I2C windows iOT find no DeviceInformation

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, iot, i2c, windowsiot

I try to communicate between a raspberry pi 3 running windows 10 IOT build 14376 insiders and a T-REX [Manual here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qodfg7lmtlrzjhz/T%27REX%20Controller%20Instruction%20Manual.pdf?dl=0) using I2C protocol. The thing is that it always crash, so after some debug process I've found that it looks like it doesn't retrieve anything from the `DeviceInformation.FinAllAsync(..)` and that cause after an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`. It should have some thing I don't understand, maybe in the device capabilities or permissions, which Microsoft tutorial doesn't mention [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/win10/samples/pinmappingsrpi2)

```
var settings = new I2cConnectionSettings(0x07);
settings.BusSpeed = I2cBusSpeed.StandardMode;
var aqs = I2cDevice.GetDeviceSelector("I2C1");
var dis = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(aqs);
int a = dis.Count; //is always equal to 0
```

Then I have a `using (I2cDevice device = await I2cDevice.FromIdAsync(dis[0].Id, settings)){...}` which fails with the `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` mentionned before

A second way I tried was using this code:

```
I2CDevice device;
var settings = new I2cConnectionSettings(0x07);
settings.BusSpeed = I2cBusSpeed.StandardMode;

var controller = await Windows.Devices.I2c.I2cController.GetDefaultAsync();
device = controller.GetDevice(settings);
```

which produce a `NullReferenceException` with the last line

Comment: It has nothing to do with the I2C device.  Exception is thrown before talking to that slave.

Answer (score 2):

You might be having the "Direct Memory Mapped Driver" enabled. You need to switch back to "Inbox Driver".

Your code should work just fine with the "Inbox Driver". However, with "Direct Memory Mapped Driver", you have to use the "Microsoft.IoT.Lightning" package to talk to your IoT device.

Follow this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/develop-your-app/lightningproviders) to use "Lightning" library, the way you setup your I2c controller looks like something below,

```
        if (LightningProvider.IsLightningEnabled)
        {
            LowLevelDevicesController.DefaultProvider = LightningProvider.GetAggregateProvider();
        }

        var i2cProvider = LightningI2cProvider.GetI2cProvider();
        var i2cControllers = await I2cController.GetControllersAsync(i2cProvider);
        var i2cController = i2cControllers[0];
        var i2cDevice = i2cController.GetDevice(new I2cConnectionSettings(0x07));
```

Note that you'll need to include

```
<iot:Capability Name="lowLevelDevices"/>
<DeviceCapability Name="109b86ad-f53d-4b76-aa5f-821e2ddf2141"/>
```

in your package [manifest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations) file, otherwise you don't have the access to all the serial peripherals.

Follow this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/develop-your-app/lightningsetup) to switch your device driver between "Inbox Driver" and "Direct Memory Mapped Driver".

Comment: Oh I haven't thought on this, thanks, I'll try this in a few hours an keep this thread up to date

Comment: How is it going? A little bit curious to find out.

Comment: Had the same Problem and your answer had been the solution in my case. Thank you very much!